# NSF CAREER Proposal For PUI Faculty

Tags: career-path, nsf

I am currently a tenure-track faculty at a PUI ("Primarily Undergrad Institution"). I recently received a research grant from NSF to start the lab and research in a small scale. Now I am planning to submit a CAREER proposal. However, I am unsure if NSF would be interested in supporting the CAREER proposal from PUI. Has anyone had luck getting CAREER from PUI, especially for the Advanced Manufacturing Program? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Talk to your program officer.

Comment: What does PUI stan for?

Comment: In mathematics, many CAREER winners come from universities classified as PUIs by the NSF. Indeed, most US universities are PUIs by NSF standards. Use the "what have been funded" search tool, you should be able to do some calculation of the percentage of PUI PIs in your specific field. One thing to consider is the fact that panel reviewers typically do not know your university type unless you specify it. Ad hoc reviewers are probably similar.

Comment: In addition to your program officer, talk to the folks at your university's grants office. They see all of the grants that have been funded and will have a perspective.

Comment: Search the awards database to see what institutions are represented.